# Read text file & count the number of 1's and 0's on individual lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a text file of votes. Each line represents 1 vote & consists of either 1's (Yes) or 0's (No). For example,

```
1
0
1
0
0
```

which contains 2 Yes votes & 3 No votes. I am attempting to write a program that reads in the text file and calculates how many yes & o votes there are. I have attempted to do this via for-loops:

```
x = 0
y = 0

for x in open('votes.txt' , 'r'):
    x += 1
for y in open('votes.txt', 'r'):
    y += 1


print("No:" , x)
print("Yes" , y)
```

The result for the 5 votes mentioned above should be:

```
No: 3
Yes: 2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way do what you want(if I understood you correctly)

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
with open("votes.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        vote = line.strip()
        c[vote] += 1

print("Yes:", c['1'])
print("No:", c['0'])
```

Comment: Note: This takes very little advantage of `Counter` to boost performance. Deleting `c = Counter()` and replacing the body of the `with` with just `c = Counter(map(str.strip, f))` would get faster code (thanks to `Counter` using a C accelerator to count input iterables, and `map(str.rstrip, f)` converting the input to a pure C iterator). (I removed your `.readlines()` because it needlessly slurps the whole file into memory, when `for line in f:` runs just as fast and has essentially fixed, low memory overhead)

Comment: I agree with you @ShadowRanger. But wouldn't changing it to a more terse version would be too "magical" for the post author?

Comment: Perhaps. Using a generator expression instead of `map` is more comfortable for some people (though it means the work isn't pushed wholly to C), and still takes advantage of `Counter`s benefits. Using `Counter` as a glorified `defaultdict(int)` just don't gain you much, that's all.

Comment: That worked well, thank you. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you to NotLost, who helped edit the post down and make it much easier to understand.